# Не полностью получаю $_GET["id"]

Tags: php, mysql, get

```
<?php
/* Основные настройки */
const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_LOGIN = 'root';
const DB_PASSWORD = '';
const DB_NAME = 'gbook';
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
/* Основные настройки */

/* Сохранение записи в БД */
if(!$link){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
/*
if(!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  echo "WTF";
}else{
  echo $name. " ". $email. " ".$msg;
}
*/

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO msgs (name, email, msg) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$msg')";

$result_of_insert = mysqli_query($link, $sql_insert);
if(!result_of_insert){
  echo mysqli_error($link);
}
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
 /* Сохранение записи в БД */

/* Вывод записей из БД*/
$sql_show = "SELECT id, name, email, msg, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) as dt FROM msgs ORDER BY id DESC";
$result_of_select = mysqli_query($link, $sql_show);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result_of_select, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//print_r($rows);
$rows_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_of_select);
/*
if($rows){
  print_r($rows);
}
*/
/* Вывод записей из БД*/

/* Удаление записи из БД */
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."&del=".$id;
$id_url = $_GET["id"];
echo $id_url,"<br>";
echo $url;
/* Удаление записи из БД */

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<p>Всего записей в гостевой книге:<?php echo $rows_count?></p>
<?php
  foreach($rows as $arrays){
    foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
      $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $arrays[dt]);
      echo "<p style=align:'left'>";
      echo "<a href='$arrays[email]'> $arrays[name] </a> $date ";
      echo "Написал :";
      echo "<br/> $arrays[msg]";
      echo "</p>";
      echo "<a href='$url'>Удалить</a>";

    };
  };

  ?>
<h3>Оставьте запись в нашей Гостевой книге</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
Имя: <br /><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <br /><input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Сообщение: <br /><textarea name="msg"></textarea><br />


<br />

<input type="submit" value="Отправить!" />

</form>
<?php
/* Вывод записей из БД */

/* Вывод записей из БД */
?>

на выходе получаю gbook и только без идентификатора
```

Comment: Дырявый для sql-инъекций этот код. И вероятно не только для них.

Comment: Хорошо, в чём вопрос?

Comment: мне нужен id записи что бы потом по нему удалить запись в базе данных